# How to plot (scatter) dataframe with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` which the indexes are strings, and the values of the `dataframe` are 1 or `NaN`
Here an example of the `dataframe`

```
         check1     check2    check3
test1     1           1        NaN
test2     NaN         NaN      NaN
test3     NaN         1        1
test4     NaN         NaN      NaN
test5     NaN         1        NaN
```

I want to plot a scatter plot:

X axis  - columns

Y axis - rows

When I'm trying this command:

```
df.plot.scatter()
```

I'm getting error `scatter() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'`

But I don't want to plot one column, I want to plot all the columns.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(([1, 1, np.nan], [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],[np.nan, 1, 1],[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],[np.nan, 1, np.nan])),
                  index=['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5'],
                  columns=['check1', 'check2', 'check3'])
df.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
plt.scatter(*np.where(df)[::-1])
plt.xticks(range(df.shape[1]), df.columns)
plt.yticks(range(df.shape[0]), df.index)
plt.show()
```

[image]